# Plivo: message not delivering to my plivo number

Tags: sms-gateway, plivo

when I try to send a message to my plivo number, it shows the following error

> "this caller id is not allowed for outbound message"

Comment: Please refer the plivo document for that response error, the link is here https://support.plivo.com/support/solutions/articles/17000082628-why-am-i-getting-this-error-this-caller-id-is-not-allowed-for-outbound-message-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you use a proper Plivo number bought on Plivo, with the "SMS" option checked, as the:

```
* src: '***********' number in your script.
```

Then use another bought number as the

```
** dst: '***********'
```

So it would look like this (depending of scripting language, this is php):

```
import plivo
auth_id = 'asdaksdbkasjhfsadk'
auth_token = 'asdsadsadasdsadasdadsadaasdadasdasda'
client = plivo.RestClient(auth_id, auth_token)
message_created = client.messages.create(

src = 'plivo number from *'
dst = 'plivo number from **'
txt = 'message you want to send'
)
```

yw.